# How to send multiple file over Rest API and then read files and merge with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How can i send multiple file over Rest api and then read files and merge with pandas.

Problem is:
I have 4 or more Files.
2 Files are csv and filename contains *_data.csv
2 Files are csv and filename contains *_prices.csv

How can i read only *_data.csv with df = pd.read_csv
and also only *_prices.csv and df1 = pd.read_csv from REST API.

After all i want to merge df with df1.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code that reads the data from the API into two dataframes: `df` for `_data` and `df1` for `_prices`.

```py
BASE_URL = 'http://example.com/api/'
OBJECTS = ['lemons', 'oranges']
dfs = []
for object in OBJECTS:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{BASE_URL}{object}_data.csv')
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
dfs = []
for object in OBJECTS:
    df = pd.read_csv(f'{BASE_URL}{object}_prices.csv')
    dfs.append(df)
df1 = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Now, assuming the dataframes have a `key` column that can be used as an index to join them you could

```
df.merge(df1, left_on='key', right_on='key')
```